# Synchronize values of two paper-inputs on change event

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component, paper-elements

I have a polymer `paper-input` element on HTML page (among other webcomponents). I need to listen on it’s value change and modify another webcomponent’s property. For a sake of simplicity, let’s imagine I need two syncronized inputs. So far, I have:

```
<paper-input id="fst" label="First" floatinglabel="First"></paper-input>
<paper-input id="snd" label="Second" floatinglabel="Second"></paper-input>
```

I want to have their values to be synchronized all the way. Currently I use following code to achieve this:

```
document.addEventListener('polymer-ready', function() {
  ['#fst', '#snd'].forEach(function(el) {
    document.querySelector(el).addEventListener("change", function(e) {
      var value = document.querySelector(el).value;
      //                     ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓ in pseudocode: other element
      document.querySelector(XOR(el)).setAttribute('value', value);
    });
  });
  ...
});
```

I definitely see this is ugly. I am sure, there is a proper way to achieve the goal, but I failed to google it and I’m totally stuck. I suppose `observes` should do the trick, but I simply can’t figure out how.

The evident code using binding variable is not working for some reason:

```
<paper-input id="fst" label="First" floatinglabel="First" value="{{ value }}">
</paper-input>
<paper-input id="snd" label="Second" floatinglabel="Second" value="{{ value }}">
</paper-input>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the declarative method and just use  something like

```
<template is="auto-binding">
  <paper-input id="fst" label="First" floatinglabel="First" value="{{value}}"></paper-input>
  <paper-input id="snd" label="Second" floatinglabel="Second" value="{{value}}"></paper-input>    
</template>
```

plunker shows it in action

http://plnkr.co/edit/3cxdOYKciKRBzROHQzgM?p=preview

edit: update answer to reflect that the use of declarative binding outside a custom element requires a auto-binding template. also it is worth noting that elements inside the auto-binding template are not accessible until the template-bound event is fired.

Comment: Surround components with `<template is="auto-binding">` was what I missed. Thanks a lot. Would you please update your answer mentioning the necessity to put components in `auto-binding` template for future visitors? I will accept then.